# WebDriver How to get selected value from a ComboBox without using Select Class in javascript

Tags: javascript, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am working on webdriver with Java. Without using Select class of Webdriver, how can I get the selected value from a combobox ?

The Markup i am working on is --

```
<select name="cmbStateName">
<option value="MH">Maharashtra</option>
<option value="HR">Harayana</option>
<option value="MP">Madhya Pradesh</option>
</select>
```

I cannot make any changes to the markup.
The reason i don't want to use the Select class is that i want to drive the test with pure Java and interaction with the Mark Up. I do not want to get the value using Java Script but i want to get it through Core Java

Comment: I am not sure what exactly is the problem. However if your intent is to get the selected text, here is the code which should work. This is in C#. Hopefully you would be able to get it working in Java.      new SelectElement(Driver.FindElementByName("cmbStateName")).SelectedOption.Text

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding what the `Select` class is. The `Select` class is literally a facade around the `WebElement` class that just searches for `option` elements that are direct descendants to it. It has literally nothing to do with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

try this (java code)

```
driver.findelement(By.name("cmbStateName")).findelement(By.xpath(".//option[@selected='selected']")).getText();
```

if doesn't work get selected option value(i.e MH or HR or MP) and convert back to display text

```
driver.findelement(By.name("cmbStateName")).findelement(By.xpath(".//option[@selected='selected']")).getAttribute("value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :  C# code (Select Class can be used from using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI )
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down")));
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText("Value1");

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in case you want to get selected value:

C# code:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

var select = new SelectElement(Driver.FindElementByName("cmbStateName"));
return select.SelectedOption.Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

Select Size
                    
                      50LB20KG6.23KG2/25LB20LB12/1LBenter code here